# PHP login form returning error

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, prepared-statement

I have created a login script below, however I have been told to use prepared statements

```
<?php
require '../php/connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);    
    $select_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $select_user);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    if($check_user>0){
        header('location:../dashboard.php');
    }else{
        header('location:/pages/loginerror.php');
    }
}
?>
```

After learning about prepared statements for security reasons i started reading prepared statements however i just do not seem to be able to get it to work below. the error i get is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_stmt_bind_param' (T_STRING) in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/timed/php/login.php on line 9"

```
<?php

require '../php/connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")
    $stmt->mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", '$username', '$password');
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $stmt);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);


    if($check_user>0){
        header('location:../dashboard.php');
    }else{
        header('location:/pages/loginerror.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$stmt->mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", '$username', '$password');` should just be `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", '$username', '$password');`

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` with a prepared statement is redundant. You should go (back) and read the manuals.

Comment: Plus, the quotes in the binding, need to be removed for the variables. Again; read the manuals on prepared statements, it's all in there.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you i am going to have another read through now as i need to understand this better.

Comment: I have also made the changes below however still get an error.

Comment: //$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $stmt); & removed the quotes & $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($stmt); however i now get Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/timed/php/login.php on line 13

Comment: You're not storing your passwords in plain-text, right?  Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're learning, instead of just telling you what you're doing wrong I'll add some explanations about **why** it's wrong:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
```

If you're using prepared statements, you *must not* use the `_escape_string()` functions. In a prepared statement you bind your parameters as a particular type (string, integer, etc.). If the variables you bind have been passed through the `_escape_string()` functions you risk PHP double-escaping certain characters and corrupting your values. You don't want that.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")
```

This line is missing a `;` at the end.

```
$stmt->mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", '$username', '$password');
```

There are two problems here:

Instead of passing the actual variables `$username` and `$password`, you're passing the **string** `'$username'` and `'$password'`. That means that your database will look for literally `"$username"` and `"$password"` instead of whatever the content of those variables is. You need to lose the quotation marks.

The second (and more important) problem is that you're mixing procedural and object-oriented styles here. You can call the `bind_param` function in two ways:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $password);
// or:
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
```

You need to choose one of these ways. In terms of what they do it really makes no difference. It's just a matter of personal preference, the outcome is exactly the same. If you're using the first option you need to tell the function which prepared statement you want to bind the variables to, using the second option you're already calling the function on the statement itself, so there's no need to add that argument.

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Good.

```
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $stmt);
```

Bad.

`mysqli_query()` is used when you want to perform a literal SQL query. You cannot use that with a prepared statement. `mysqli_stmt_excute()` has already executed the query on your database. You need to remove this call to `mysqli_query()`.

Keep in mind that executing your prepared statement can fail. If, for some reason, your prepared statement fails to execute (maybe there's a typo in your SQL query, the database connection has dropped, etc.) `mysqli_stmt_execute()` will return `false`. It is always wise to check for this, to make debugging things a heck of a lot easier.

```
$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
```

This is almost correct, except that you need to retrieve the number of rows from the *statement* itself, since that is your query's interaction with the database. <s>You need to call `mysqli_num_rows($stmt)` instead.</s> **Edit**: As you rightly pointed out, `mysqli_num_rows()` doesn't work on statements. You need to use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)` instead.

If you've been typing along, you should have ended up with something similar to:

```
<?php

require '../php/connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $password);
    $success = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if (!$success) {
        echo "Query failed: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        die();
    }

    $check_user = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    if($check_user>0){
        header('location:../dashboard.php');
    }else{
        header('location:/pages/loginerror.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: By the way: from the looks of your code, you're storing passwords in your database as plain text. If that's true, ***don't!*** Read up on [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Thank you this helped a great deal. After reading i ended up with the same code with the exception of calling success "result". for some reason it is still failing at "$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);" with the error of Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, The logic of the code i now understand but not why it is failing

Comment: $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($stmt); also changes $stmt to $result with no luck

Comment: Whoops, yes, that should be `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)` instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again! i have ran into 1 last issue. Now i have changed that it jumps straight to header('location:/pages/loginerror.php');. I have checked echo $check_user; and it returns 0 and i checked echo $success; and it returns 1 the correct value however... when i change $check_user = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($result); i get Warning: mysqli_stmt_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given. I have read about boolean and the mysqli_stmt_num_rows chould be able to handle that. I could be wrong

Comment: It should be `$stmt` instead of `$result`

Comment: yep as above. Whet i do use $stmt i jumps to header('location:/pages/loginerror.php' even though username and password is correct. I echo username, password and there are correct however when i echo $check user = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt); it returns result as 0

Comment: After much reading i have found that before $check_user = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt); I have had to add mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); @rickdenhaan - Thank you so much for your help this has bought my understanding on a long way :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require '../php/connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $password);
    $success = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if (!$success) {
        echo "Query failed: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        die();
    }

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $check_user = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    if($check_user>0){
        header('location:../dashboard.php');
    }else{
        echo 'Login Failed';
    }
}
?>
```